# Strange top margin for the first and second UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I got a `UICollectionView`, my setup:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView == self.navigationCollectionView)
        return 24;
    else
        return 0;
}
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    if (collectionView == self.navigationCollectionView)
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(14.5, 15, 0, 15);
    else // chart collection
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (collectionView == self.navigationCollectionView) {
        DashboardModel *dashModel = [self getDashBoardCacheAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = dashModel.dashboardTitle;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        [label sizeToFit];
        return CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width,self.navigationCollectionView.bounds.size.height);
    }
}
```

But when running, it shows like this:

```
First cell frame is (39,0,85,44) 
Second cell frame is (148,14.5,50,44)
```

The first cell's top inset is not correctly set. What's wrong with it?

EDIT:
I feel the cell is auto-centered by UICollectionView. Can we set not to auto-center?

[image: first cell frame is (39,0,85,44) while the second cell frame is (148,14.5,50,44)]

Comment: If you open up the sidebar in the visual layout debugger in Xcode, you can see the constraints that are applied like [this](https://i.imgur.com/L44uEyC.png). What do yours look like?

Comment: what you mean? I don't setup any constraints. pure frame based

Comment: You should really check out constraints then. You setup some insets in `insetForSectionAtIndex`. Are you sure it takes the right insets? Could you log them and verify?

Comment: I already shown in the screenshot, the top margin for second cell is correct, while the first one is not. the second cell('empty') top margin is 14.5,while the first one ('Test') is 0. BTW, I set the collection view and its cells' `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO

Comment: I feel the cell is auto-centered by UICollectionView. Can we set not to auto-center?